# Why are the eigenvalues of symmetric real matrices real?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that a real symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues?

Comment: See too http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746223/besides-being-symmetric-when-will-a-matrix-have-only-real-eigenvalues

Comment: It's funny how none of these showed up when I was typing up the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Think about the *complex* inner product $(u,Au)$ when $u$ is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

$A\mathbf{u}  = \lambda\mathbf{u}\Rightarrow A\mathbf{u}^*  = \lambda^*\mathbf{u}^* \Rightarrow -\mathbf{u}^T A\mathbf{u}^*  =- \lambda^*\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{u}^* \Rightarrow \mathbf{u}^H A\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}^T A\mathbf{u}^* =\lambda \mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{u} - \lambda^*\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{u}^* \Rightarrow 0 = (\lambda -\lambda^*)\mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{u} \Rightarrow\lambda =\lambda^*. $

Comment: I don´t understand what is $u^H$