# Geometric interpretation of a non-symmetric matrix having only real eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a geometric interpretation of a non-symmetric matrix having only real eigenvalues?

It [appears](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7601) that multiplying random matrices with IID random entries eventually produces a matrix with only real eigenvalues, wondering if this can be turned into a statement about how random linear maps transform a vector.

For instance, code below multiples $10\ 2\times 2$ random matrices, eigenvalues are almost always real.

```
n = 2;
depth = 10;
dist = NormalDistribution[];
sample := RandomVariate[dist, {n, n}]/Sqrt[n];
sampled := Nest[sample . # &, sample, depth - 1];
Eigenvalues[sampled] (* {-0.859186, 0.613002} *)
```

Some trajectories of 1,1 vector evolving in accordance with random 2D linear transformation. It appears that power iteration converges to a line for all matrices with real eigenvalues but not for complex-valued ones

([code](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-real-eigenvalues.nb))

#### Real-valued eigenvalues

[image]

#### Complex valued eigenvalues

[image]

Comment: It may be helpful to look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746223/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734175).

Comment: Somewhat loosely speaking, real eigenvalues correspond to an axis the matrix scales and nonreal eigenvalues correspond to a plane the matrix rotates.

Comment: @BenGrossmann can the intuition of "non-real eigenvalues correspond to rotations" be made rigorous?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Not who you're at-ing, but if $v, \bar v$ are eigenvectors with conjugate nonreal eigenvalues and $v = v_1 + iv_2$ for real $v_1, v_2$, then you can compute that $av_1 + bv_2$ transforms to $$r[(a\cos\theta - b\sin\theta)v_1 + (b\cos\theta + a\sin\theta)v_2]$$ where $re^{\pm i\theta}$ are the eigenvalues. This is a rotation matrix applied to the $v_1, v_2$ basis followed by a scaling by $r$; it's not necessarily a rotation though because $v_1, v_2$ need not be orthogonal, but it's closely related.