# Realness of eigenvalues of $\left(E[xx']\otimes I + I\otimes E[xx']\right)^{-1} E[xx'\otimes xx']$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $x$ is a random variable in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $I$ is a $d\times d$ identity. What's the easiest way of showing that eigenvalues of the following matrix are real?

$$\left(E[xx']\otimes I + I\otimes E[xx']\right)^{-1} E[xx'\otimes xx']$$

This might be equivalent to showing that the $\Lambda,\Phi$, solution to generalized problem is real:

$$E[xx'\otimes xx'] \Phi = (E[xx']\otimes I + I\otimes E[xx'])\Phi \Lambda$$

<sub><sup>[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-realness-of-ratio-eigenvalues.nb)</sup></sub>

Comment: It's a product of two symmetric matrices, so it's not symmetric

Comment: Thanks, see also the last paragraph of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113859

Comment: @user196574 Yes, there seems to be some confusion over whether "positive definite" requires symmetric. If you treat matrix as quadratic form, then it doesn't matter whether it's symmetric. If you treat it as linear operation, it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to note that all of your expectation matrices are symmetric and positive definite. Denote $P = \left(E[xx']\otimes I + I\otimes E[xx']\right), Q = E[xx' \otimes xx']$. The matrices $P,Q$ are symmetric positive definite. It follows that $P^{-1}Q$ is similar to the matrix
$$
P^{1/2}(P^{-1}Q)P^{-1/2} = P^{-1/2}QP^{-1/2}.
$$
This is a matrix of the form $M^TQM$ for a real matrix $M$. It follows that this matrix is positive semidefinite, and thus has real eigenvalues.

Comment: How do you know anticommutator {E[xx'],I} is positive definite?

Comment: A Kronecker product of positive definite matrices is positive definite, and a sum of positive definite matrices is positive definite.

Comment: Also, I'm not used to your usage of "anticommutator". You could say that is is the [Kronecker sum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html) of $E[xx']$ with itself. The anticommutator more commonly refers to $\{A,B\} = AB + BA$.

Comment: ok, Kronecker sum seems like a better term

Comment: By the way, it is notable that the product of symmetric matrices can potentially have complex (non-real) eigenvalues. For instance,
$$
\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}.
$$
This is ruled out if one of the matrices is positive semidefinite.

Comment: btw, any thoughts whether definition of "positive definite" should require symmetric or not?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Personally I think it should require symmetry, but that's not a universal convention so I include the descriptor "symmetric" for clarity.

Comment: BTW, a related curious phenomenon is that multiplying random matrices together eventually gives a matrix with only real eigenvalues -- [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744629/geometric-interpretation-of-a-non-symmetric-matrix-having-only-real-eigenvalues)